# Dapper Cast Exception on NULL value in column

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

I'm using SQLite and it's closure extension to store a hierarchy. The non-closure table is created as

```cs
_connection.Execute(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    parent_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id)
);");
```

The root node is inserted with `parent_id` set to `NULL`. The class for Dapper to cast to and from is

```cs
public class TestRecord
{
    public long id;
    public string name;
    public long? parent_id;
}
```

In my mind, Dapper shouldn't have any problems reading root or non-root nodes, as the column in question is clearly marked as nullable. However, querying all entries like so:

```cs
_connection.Query<TestRecord>(@"SELECT * FROM category;");
```

will throw on the root node, because it can't cast something (which is weird, because there are no 32bit ints involved anywhere):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.DataException: 
Error parsing column 2 (parent_id=1 - Int64) ---> 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 
  'System.Int32'.
```

A *workaround* that returns correct results is

```cs
.Query<TestRecord>(@"SELECT id, IFNULL(parent_id, 0), name FROM category;");
```

But this is a no-go for several reasons. I specifically don't want to list all columns in the query, nor do I want to introduce the `parent_id` special case.

Not using Dapper and mapping it manually works just fine with the original query, same goes for the sqlite CLI of course.

So, how can I get Dapper to accept and map the proper entries?

Edit: I'm using Dapper 1.50.4 and dotnet core 2.0.

Comment: I totally agree - this looks odd. I can take a peek, but I'll need to setup SQLite  etc - any particular version you are using? and what ADO.NET provider **exactly** are you using? System.Data.SQLite ? or?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Data.SQLite (https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite). I can try to prepare a minimal package that's setup to repro this and give you access on GitHub. You'd still need to compile closure.c (I can only supply a linux-amd64 version). I also filed an issue here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/917

Comment: My hunch is that this is weak metadata and problems with nulls - i.e. all it knows is "number, null" and it asserts the wrong thing. Still, dapper should cope with it. The even more awkward thing is IIRC this can manifest as the schema changing mid-grid, so to fix *fully* could be even more fun. I'll take a look when I get a chance (not at a PC), but: "library fixes" definitely.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll put more details on how to repro this in the GitHub issue. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @mınxomaτ - What happens if you use the actual column names instead of  `*` like this: `_connection.Query<TestRecord>(@"SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM category;");`

Comment: @MarcGravell BTW, using `IFNULL` also doesn't work, because now *all* rows have the `parent_id` set to `0`. Issuing the same query in the sqlite CLI yields a correct result set (just one row, where `parent_id` is NULL set to 0).

Comment: @MarcGravell I found the bug with `IFNULL`. When using this cast, Dapper somehow thinks that the column *name* is `IFNUL(parent...`. If I explicitly rename the column, a typed query will work. So this is the *actual* workaround: `_connection.Query<T>($@"SELECT id, {string.Join(",", _fields)}, IFNULL(parent_id, 0) AS parent_id FROM {TableName};");`.

That doesn't fix the underlying Dapper issue, but at least I can somewhat use it now ...

Comment: @mınxomaτ Dapper doesn't make any guesses about column names - it doesn't do much SQL parsing, for example - it lets the data-reader tell it the column names. If Dapper thinks the name is `IFNUL(...`, then that's what the DB back-end chose to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Marc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172218/dapper-cast-exception-on-null-value-in-column/48345075#comment83461819_48172218) this should not happen and it warrents a library fix. The issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/917) and also affects other people.

Comment: Though it's true that this is an issue that should be fixed eventually (hopefully), @vitidev has a true workaround (using a TypeConverter) below that requires no query or model changes.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for sqlite nullable types. [link](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/642)

```
public class NullableLongHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<long?>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, long? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
            parameter.Value = value.Value;
        else
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }

    public override long? Parse(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value is DBNull) return null;
        return Convert.ToInt64(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new NullableLongHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create your table with "INTEGER", Sqlite will create int32, however you have a long in your model, I guess this is trowing the invalid cast exception, BigInt would have to be used to give a long.

So you should either change your request to :

```
_connection.Execute(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  parent_id BIGINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id)
);");
```

Or use a model that match your request :

```
public class TestRecord
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int? parent_id;
}
```

I guess your request with "IFNULL(parent_id, 0)" is working because it include a cast, as 0 can be considered as int32.

Comment: `Sqlite will create int32` - Do you have a reference for that? The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) describe INTEGER as a general container, `stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value`. Regardless of that, both your solutions don't work. They throw the same error, just the receiving type changes (e.g. `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Nullable\`1[System.Int32]'`)

Comment: The reference is how the resulting table is after both query, integer will result in INT(4) BigInt in INT(8), I think on the docs you have to look at the Affinity table. 
And as specified in the doc, the size is dependant on the magnitude, if there is no magnitude like in here, default value of size (4) will be created.
But with that said, I wasn't aware of the issue on the nullable foreign key. I would still advise to wath the resulting dataType on the actual table, to avoid issue.